# What are the properties of the adjunction for a bimonad?

Tags: ct.category-theory

We know that a Frobenius Monad is the result of an ambidextrous adjunction.

We have the [definition of a bimonad here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1163).

What are the properties of the adjunction that generates a bimonad?

What I mean by this is just, we know some basic facts about an ambidextrous adjunction.  What are the basic facts about the adjunction that generates a bimonad?